# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Magento 2.2.4

Tags: php, json, api, magento, magento2

The coupon inbox is not working on my Magento 2.2.4 site's payment page.

When i checked with Chrome's developer tool; i saw this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.process (error-processor.js:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (set-coupon-code.js:57)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3362)
at done (jquery.js:9842)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311)
```

- there is no wrong on file permissions and chmods; i'm sure.

I re-install magento and theme again to make a test; but the problem is the same even a fresh install. (the theme owners are saying 'they are tested several times; and everyhing is ok at their site; and also i saw their site is working too)

Can it be a server config problem? (i checked all topics on Stackoverflow and Google; but couldn't get the solution)

By the way; i also see this error on chrome console at the same page:

```
PUT https://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/7da32163da52d8ea1521572a8799c86a/coupons/asd 404 ()
```

In Network tab; i see this error (example.com is my site):

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/02432152dc488bb6b7435911edb57505/coupons/test
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: 104.31.89.116:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

104.31.89.116 is Clodflare's IP i think.

By the way; i also saw this error in Apache logs (but not sure if its about this problem or not)

```
2018/06/08 20:53:29 [error] 3436#3436: *28844 upstream prematurely 
closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 
162.158.89.48, server: www.example.com, request: "GET 
/customer/section/load/sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1528491190921 
HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.31.32.231:82/customer/section/load/?
sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1528491190921", host: 
"www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
```

not sure what these IP'S are: 172.31.32.231, 162.158.89.48 (they are not my server's IP)

- i also disabled my CDN (keyCDN); but the problem is still the same. (as like my fresh test magento+theme install)
- the coupon input is working in cart page page (i mean; there is no error in coupon process)

Comment: your php scripts are throwing an error. View network tab to check what php is returning.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for your comment; could you please re-check the updated question(at below)

Comment: does anyone have any idea?

Comment: it's some error magneto is throwing, but we don't see the error yet. check Network-tab -> click on link link in "name" -> click on "response" (a column to the right)

Comment: @Jeff Thank you so much again.. Could you please look at these; am i looking wrong place? https://ibb.co/btH908  https://ibb.co/fVHWDT

Comment: now it's the right place! In the first image you see "404 Page not found" for the file/route "COUPON001". You have the same before for 'coupons/asd' and 'coupons/test'. I think (and this is really just a guess) that either the magneto router has a problem, or a wrong .htaccess,... don't know really.

Comment: maybe its because of PUT method in rest api of Magento. i'm using post method in my other scripts with no probem. but put method always returns 404 error..  maybe its about server config; don't know :S

Comment: could be, yes. I unfortunately have not a clue about magneto, and the error doesn't give too much of information..

Comment: @Jeff Thank you so much again :)